# Запрос MySQL с подсчетом строк

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы в базе данных. Первая `places` заведения (idPlace, name, date) вторая `comments` - комментарии к нему (id, autor, text). Задача составить запрос, который выводит список заведений, считая количество комментариев.

Составил такой...

```
SELECT idPlace, name, date, COUNT(*) FROM places 
JOIN comments places.idPlace = comments.id 
GROUP BY idPlace
```

...но беда в том, что комментарии есть не для всех заведений. И соответственно они в запросе не выдаются. Как подправить?

П.с. Стоит ли использовать такие заморочки или лучше просто вставить в цикле (в php) еще один короткий запрос на количество комментов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

копайте в сторону LEFT JOIN, почитайте вот тут http://blog.sergey-lysenko.ru/2011/12/inner-left-and-right-joins.html

LEFT JOIN
Возвращаются все данные из «левой» таблицы, даже если не найдено соответствий в «правой» таблице

Comment: ух ты))) Спасибо!

Comment: если ответ подошел отметьте ответ как правильный поставив галочку возле ответа, незачто)

Comment: "вы можете принять правильный ответ только через 7 минут" Жду)

Comment: а)ну это не учел)